# ng-repeat nested loop

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm looping through an array and using a filter to separate my results grouped by day. It works, but now I can't seem to access the variables inside the second loop, where I have the filter.

```
<ion-list class="list list-inset"  ng-repeat="(key, value) in Jobs | groupBy: 'FilterTime'">
    <div class="item item-divider"><center>{{key}}</center></div>

    <div class="list list-inset" >
        <div class="item item-divider"><center>{{JobCount}} jobs</center></div>

        <a class="item item-icon-left item-icon-right" href="#/app/viewjob/{{job.BookingPublicId}}" ng-repeat="job in value  | groupBy: 'BookingTime'">
            <i class="icon ion-android-car "></i>
            <h2>{{job.EndAddress1stLine}}</h2>
            <p>{{job.StartAddressPostCode}} <b>></b> {{job.EndAddressPostCode}}</p>

            <p ng-show="job.Status == 0"><b>Waiting</b> - {{job.BookingTime * 1000 | date:'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm'}}</p>
            <p ng-show="job.Status == 2"><b>Accepted</b> - {{job.BookingTime * 1000 | date:'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm'}}</p>
            <p ng-show="job.Status == 4"><b>Enroute to job</b> - {{job.BookingTime * 1000 | date:'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm'}}</p>
            <p ng-show="job.Status == 6"><b>Waiting for customer</b> - {{job.BookingTime * 1000 | date:'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm'}}</p>
            <p ng-show="job.Status == 8"><b>Job Started</b> - {{job.BookingTime * 1000 | date:'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm'}}</p>
            <p ng-show="job.Status == 10"><b>Complete</b> - {{job.BookingTime * 1000 | date:'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm'}}</p>
            <!--<span class="item-note">{{job.StartAddressPostCode}} > {{job.EndAddressPostCode}}</span>-->
            <i class="icon ion-chevron-right "></i>
        </a>
    </div>
    <!--<p>{{value.BookingPublicId}} <b>></b> {{EndAddressPostCode}}</p>-->
</ion-list>
```

Now, anything in job.variable doesn't load but if I do just job it'll spit out all the json.

[image]

As you can see, the grouping works; but I can't see any data. If I spit out just job I get this:

[image]

**EDIT:** The data looks like:

```
[
{
"BookingPublicId": "C1LY482T",
"BookingTime": 1462238100,
"FilterTime": "03/05/2016",
"BookingName": "",
"Status": 1,
"PassengersName": "John Smith",
"PassengersMobile": null,
"Fare": "544.13",
"StartAddressPostCode": "RG2 0GH",
"StartAddress1stLine": "Drake Way",
"EndAddressPostCode": "M90 1QX",
"EndAddress1stLine": "Drake Way",
"Status1": 1,
"Resp": "OK"
},
{
"BookingPublicId": "ZGX39WNB",
"BookingTime": 1462268100,
"FilterTime": "03/05/2016",
"BookingName": "",
"Status": 1,
"PassengersName": "John Smith",
"PassengersMobile": null,
"Fare": "544.13",
"StartAddressPostCode": "RG2 0GH",
"StartAddress1stLine": "Drake Way",
"EndAddressPostCode": "M90 1QX",
"EndAddress1stLine": "Drake Way",
"Status1": 1,
"Resp": "OK"
}
]
```

Comment: Can you please post your JSON/array that you are looping?

Comment: I've added it in below

Comment: Thank you! Can you still add the filter function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your second picture it seems `job` is an Array not an Object so `job.EndAddress1stLine` wouldn't work.

If your `job` just contains one Object you could use something like `(job[0]).EndAddress1stLine`. (This also means that there might be something wrong with your data structure. You should look at it again if you have the possibility to get just an Object)

If it contains multiple Objects you would need (as mentioned in the Comments) another `ng-repeat` over `job`.

Comment: How would I display the information for each row then?

Comment: @Tom You should use `ng-repeat` for each array that you encounter.

Comment: @Tom keep in mind that if you use `[0]` then it'll only use the first object in your `job` array. To use the second one you'll need another `ng-repeat`, or a manual `[0]` and `[1]`.

Comment: @Tom it would be interesting to know how the `value` Object looks like and if the `job` Array contains just one Object or multiple Objects